# Issue with connecting on SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, connection, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2014-express

I've installed SQL Server 2014 from dreamspark website... The weird part about it is when I try to connect to the server, it gives me a network related error (could be possibly due to the fact that the SQL Server service is not running). The weird part is that I went to the SQL Server Configuration manager and found no services there at all. Here is what I mean: 
[image]

How am I supposed to start the SQL server service if its not there... This is very confusing to me... Am  I supposed to install anything else besides this? In past I just installed SQL Server, start the service and that was it... I also have installed Visual studio 2015 (if that matters)

Comment: What **exactly** did you install?? Quite obviously, you haven't actually installed any SQL Server **database engine**, or else it would show up in the "SQL Server Services" list .....

Comment: SQL Server management studio 2014 from dreamspark

Comment: Management Studio is ***ONLY*** the management Gui - it is ***NOT*** an actual database server engine! You need to download either SQL Server 2014 **Express with Tools**, or a non-Express version of SQL Server 2014, to get the **engine** of the database to which you can then connect....

Comment: Is SQL Server express 2014 with tools enough for development ?

Comment: SQL Server Express can do quite a lot. Its main limitation is the size of database. However it can't do everything that SQL Server Enterprise can do. If you need specific features of Enterprise edition, then you should use the Developer edition.

Comment: Or you could use Azure SQL Database.

Comment: @richard345 I installed SQL Server 2014/developer edition on my local machine. I hope its gonna be enough

Comment: The Developer edition has all the features of the Enterprise edition; it's just the licensing that's different--you can't use Developer for production use. If you mean you hope your local machine will be powerful enough, it should be ok on a reasonably powerful workstation providing the data size is not too big. Personally, I prefer to develop with SQL Server running in a VM on a separate Windows Server box.

Comment: I'm working with i5 4210U processor/8GB of RAM... Hopefully it's enough @richard345

Comment: You might want to double the RAM to 16GB. SQL Server is pretty hungry for RAM. Running a single instance of the database engine on a server, I allocate at least 4 GB of RAM. If you're going to run Analysis Services and Reporting Services it could need twice that. To be clear, I'm talking about a development environment with light loading and moderate data. See MSDN > Hardware and Software Requirements for Installing SQL Server 2014 -- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506(v=sql.120).aspx

Comment: Yeah I referred to the link that you posted. This clears up pretty much everything... I'll double the RAM on 16GB just to make sure I don't run out of memory... I'm gonna be working with loads and loads of data... Thanks! @richard345